# Can I specify the datatype of a class parameter in python?

Tags: python

I'm confused because a video I'm watching says I can force the datatype by adding it after the parameter with a colon `def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):`. However, this throws invalid syntax.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        # Run validations to the received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater or equal to zero!"

        # Assign to self object
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

item1 = Item("Phone", 100, 1)
item2 = Item("Laptop", 1000, 3)

print(item1.calculate_total_price())
print(item2.calculate_total_price())
```

Comment: What is your syntax error?

Comment: What is the python version you're using? (output of `python -V` command)

Comment: Yes, type hint and annotations are available in Python >= 3.6. it is important to understand though, these are type *hints*, they don't prevent your code from compiling or even prevent the wrong type object being passed at runtime

Comment: If you are getting errors, always post the full error message including the stack trace. Please see [ask] and the [help]

Comment: In any case, note "a video I'm watching says I can force the datatype by adding it after the parameter with a colon" that is not true. Type hints in **no way** force the type of the argument they are annotating

Comment: Interesting, my venv was using an older version of Python. Thanks for the clarification juanpa I get that it's annotation.